# PECL install with --configureoptions not working - Memcache

Tags: php, macos, memcached, pear, pecl

Lately, I have been trying to install the `pecl memcache` PHP extension on OSX Catalina with `brew memcached` installed and I'm getting the following error every time I try the install process:

```sh
configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
```

I have tried with `pecl install memcache` and with `pecl install --configureoptions='with-zlib-dir="path"' memcache` to no avail. It always gets the same point and it fails.

[image: Screen Shot 2021-07-10 at 12 56 14 AM]

From what I have reviewed on different topics regarding the installation of the package the issue seems to be with the `-D` option in the `pecl install` command, because when I do a manual install from the source code passing the argument `--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11` to the `./configure` command it works like a charm and installs the package but is now not listed in `pecl list` installed packages and as so it cannot be uninstalled.

The issue is I need `pecl` to manage the installation of the package to be able to uninstall it any time when the environment changes from project to protect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix for this (found via https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=56522) is to use the PHP_ZLIB_DIR variable instead of --with-zlib-dir.

i.e. `PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11 pecl install memcache`

I've struggled with the -D option before as well - near as I can tell it's completely broken.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it works perfectly the way it is intended to work. The only change I suggest, for anyone else looking at this issue would be to export the path in `.bashrc` or in `.zshrc` for future installations with `echo "export PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11 pecl install memcache" > .bashrc`. 

And remember to use `sudo` if possible during the install to avoid permission issues